# FFMPEG - How can I keep a video to a original resolution, but if its over 1280×720 then scale it back to 1280×720

Tags: ffmpeg

so i have a little problem with my current ffmpeg script. I'm trying to keep the video in its original resolution if its not over 1280×720. But anything that is above 1280×720, down-scale/resize it to 1280×720.

Currently i have the below filter:

`-filter:v "scale='min(1280,iw)':min'(720,ih)':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2"`

However, this by the looks of it changes all videos to 1280×720, which then causes black bars on videos that are for example recorded on phone etc...

Example:

If 1920x1080 > downscale to 1280×720

If anything above 1280×720 > downscale to 1280×720

If 1280×720 > Keep it

If anything below 1280×720 > Keep the original resolution

Hope anyone could help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: remove `,pad=...` or change `pad=...` part to `pad='min(1280,iw)':'min(720,iw/16*9)':(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2` or `pad='min(1280,iw)':'min(720,ih)':(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2`

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов i can't thank you enough. You dont know how much you have helped me.

Removing `,pad=...` worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mediainfo to check the height/width.
To check if height is greater-than/equal to:

```
(( $(mediainfo --Output='Video;%Height%' Big_Buck_Bunny_1080p_surround.mp4) >= 720 )) && echo "greater or equal to 720" || echo "less than 720"
```

To check if height is less than:

```
(( $(mediainfo --Output='Video;%Height%' Big_Buck_Bunny_1080p_surround.mp4) < 720 )) && echo "less than 720" || echo "greater than 720"
```